# GDAL C++ code for JPEG2000 compressed NITF

Tags: jpeg-2000, nitf

I need to convert JPEG2000 compressed multi-image NITF files to GeoTIFF or TIFF in C++ through GDAL. I am trying it with NITFDataset but unable to do so. If someone has any sample code, please post.

Comment: If you can share some test data, please do.

Comment: @user30184, I am unable to attach the file, but you can download one from link: https://gwg.nga.mil/ntb/baseline/software/testfile/Nitfv2_1/scen_2_1.html. I am using ns3005b.nsf  Thanks